# Can I restore backups taken from Titanium Backup on a non-rooted phone?

Tags: restore, titanium-backup

I have both rooted and a non-rooted phones, there are some apps in my rooted phone which I took a backup using 'Titanium Backup' can I restore it on my non-rooted phone using any method?

Comment: For better compatibility with non-rooted devices, I strongly recommend taking a look at ADB backups. Start with the hints in our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) and [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) to familiarize yourself with this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of backup you want to restore. If it's an XML backup (bookmarks, messages, call log or Wi-Fi access points) then you can restore it. In the case of app+data pairs, only the app can be restored (without its data), and that is only if it's a non-system app.

XML backups can be restored by pressing the Menu button, then scrolling down and selecting the option 'Restore data from XML'.
Non-system apps can be restored by choosing their respective entries in the 'Backup/Restore' tab, selecting the desired backup, then picking the 'App only' button from the popup.

Comment: You can restore any TiBu backup on a non-rooted device after rooting it ;) (sorry, bad joke). Arielle, could you please [edit] your answer and include how restoring those XML backups on a non-rooted device is done? And also, how to restore the (non-system) app? I know (how) the latter works, but am a bit sceptical concerning the XML part.